# How can I weight my variables by another variable?

Tags: r, rstudio, spss

In SPSS I can choose a variable which I want to use for weighting other variables just by using "weights_by".

For my studies I have to use Rstudio now. When I do the above thing and open it in R, they weights will disappear. How can I do this in R then?

Something like:

```
"weights(pspwhgt)" (without"") is not working for me...
```

I'm on a totally beginner level. I have my variable gender and I want to weight it by my other variable pspwhgt. How can I do this without being a genius in math or programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike SPSS, weights in R are applied at the operation level rather than globally. So, how you specify and use weights depends on what operation you want to perform. Many R functions have a `weights` argument (such as `lm()`, etc.). You may also want `weighted.mean()`, etc.

Comment: Im thinking of sth like this: table(data$gendertypes). Do i have to write sth like weights.table(data$gendertypes),weightvariable) ? (i dont have access to R right now)

Comment: @loko84 You may want to look at the [survey package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) and specifically, the `svytable()` function.